# Reference is held beyond being used eventhough the scope has ownership of the variable

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, scope, future

I have some code that looks like this:

```rust
async move {
    let res = do_sth(&state).await;
    (state, res)
}.boxed()
```

(Full example: https://gitlab.com/msrd0/async-issue)

I'd say that the `async move` block takes ownership of `state` and passes a reference of `state` along to the `do_sth` method, which is an `async fn`. However, the compiler also keeps `&state` across the `await` bound, and I have no idea why it would do that:

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:30:5
   |
30 |         }.boxed()
   |           ^^^^^ future returned by `read_all` is not `Send`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `(dyn std::any::Any + std::marker::Send + 'static)`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
  --> src/main.rs:28:14
   |
28 |             let res = do_sth(&state).await;
   |                       ^^^^^^^------^^^^^^^- `&state` is later dropped here
   |                       |      |
   |                       |      has type `&gotham::state::State`
   |                       await occurs here, with `&state` maybe used later
```

I tried placing the `do_sth` call without the `await` into its own block but that didn't fix the error etiher.

Is there any way to avoid this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is pretty clearly not related to ownership or lifetimes:

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
```

`gotham_restful::State` does not implement the [`Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Sync.html) trait, which means that its reference `&state` is not thread-safe. However, you are passing that reference to asynchronous function, which is then awaited, and the Rust compiler automatically infers that that function is not thread safe, so the entire block become "not thread safe". The return value of the `read_all` method has the `+ Send` constraint, however, requiring the returned future to be thread safe, so this causes an error.

---

One possible solution is to rewrite `do_sth` to be a regular function that returns a future. This way you can ensure that the returned future from that function implements `Send` and is thread-safe, instead of relying on the compiler to infer where it is thread safe or not:

```rust
fn do_sth(_state: &State) -> impl Future<Output = NoContent> + Send {
//   require that the future of this function is thread-safe ---^

    async move {
        Default::default()
    }
}
```

Note that this will not actually allow you to do anything that is not thread safe, however it will instruct the compiler that the `do_sth` function should be thread safe, instead of attempting to manually infer whether it should be or not.

Comment: Ok does that mean that there is no way I can use any reference to `State` inside the `async {}` block? Because adding `+ Send` doesn't change whether or not the compiler thinks it's safe to send that future ...

Comment: @msrd0 Yes, that's true. You can use it before the async block, but you can't use it inside of the async block, because it's not thread safe. (This seems to be an unfortunate consequence of the way the `State` type is implemented.)

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-03-shared-state.html talk about how to wrap things for improved thread safety.